# Wordpress rewrite rules not working

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I have created a plugin and i have gotten rewrite rules to work using my .htaccess file. I would like to make this work from my plugin instead to keep everything contained from within there.

Im trying to do this via the wordpress rewrite but nothing i do it working with this. I have even tried a basic rewrite and it wont work either. readme.html is a page in the root directory. I simply want testpage to display this page. The other rules i have in my .htaccess are far more complicated than this so, if i cant get this one to work i have no hope with the complicated ones.

```
    add_action('init', 'add_actor_url');
    function add_actor_url()
    {
        add_rewrite_rule('^testpage','readme.html','top');
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. (Although I would advise against flushing rules on every call.) Maybe try vardumping something in that function to see if it get's called.

Comment: If i go to the main menu and go to permalink settings and just save them without making a change i can see these rules are getting written to the .htaccess file. Is there a way to know if these rules exist and only apply/flush them if this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush rewrite rules after adding or modifying rewrite rules in WordPress.

`flush_rewrite_rules()` can be used to flush rules.

For more info check these links :

https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

Comment: This didnt work, but you are on the right road. I went to the admin panel and in the permalinks menu i just clicked save. This made all of  the rules write to the .htaccess file